# Using facet_grid to plot two graphs with different discrete values

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, facet

My first post to stackoverflow. Hope I can get some help.

I am looking into the NOAA natural event database. I would like to display a set of graphs that show what the financial impact is based on what type of event occurred (flood, tornado, etc.). The data base splits the financial damage into two categories: property damage and crop damage.  I would like to display two graphs showing the total cost due to property and crop damage. There are many categories of events (>900), so I would only like to display the top 10 contributors in each category (property or crop damage) and rank them individually in descending order. The problem is, the top events are different for the two categories. When I try to plot this using facet_grid it shows all the contributors between the two categories.

[image: damages.graph]

Here is the code:

```
## Melt results into usable format
type.melt <- melt(by_event_dmg, measure.vars=c("prop","crop"), variable.name="type")
melt.arrange <- arrange(type.melt, type, desc(value))
melt.arrange <- melt.arrange[c(1:10,986:995),]
z <- ggplot(melt.arrange, aes(x= reorder(EVTYPE, -value),y = value))
z + geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  facet_grid(type ~ ., scales="free") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1))+
  ggtitle("Damages from Natural Events") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

Comment: Use `facet_wrap(~ type, scales="free", nrow=2)`.

Comment: Actually if you switch the formatting to display the graphs in one row, you will get the proper categories, but the second graph isn't formatted correctly to show in descending order??

Comment: You may get some reply if you provide a representative data-set that can replicate your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Image with graphs in one row is closer to the result I was looking for. Just need to order the crop data in descending order.

[image: image corrected to show only proper categories]